# Redirect page using htaccess or change https for http

Tags: .htaccess

I need to change https for http becouse waiting for ssl, or redirect to other side. 
I have already tried:

Redirection:

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 302 "/" "https://new.page.com/"
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

But nothing works.
What is the problem?

Comment: If you try to implement such a rule in a dynamic configuration file (as your tag ".htaccess" implies), then you need to enable the interpretation of such files first. Did you do that? How did you check that this part works?

Comment: Apart from that: you are aware that even _with_ working redirection your clients will still get blocked by their browsers and see a big fat warning in their browsers? Something _you cannot change_ without a certificate?

Comment: do you want to force http into https or https into http?